# Nodejs app using Mailjet throwing a confusing error

Tags: node.js, email, mailjet

I'm building an app using Mailjet, and using their connection example.

```
app.get('/send',function(req,res){
...        
    var request = mailjet
            .post("send")
            .request({
                <request stuff, email details>
            });
        request
            .on('success', function (response, body) {
                <handle response>
            })
            .on('error', function (err, response) {
                <handle error>
            });
```

Getting this error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Unsuccessful
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/node-mailjet/mailjet-client.js:203:23
```

When I go to the Mailjet client and ask it to log the error, it tells me:

```
{ [Error: Unauthorized]
  original: null,
  ...
```

Anyone have an idea of where I should start troubleshooting?

Update: saw this in the error output:

```
header: 
  { server: 'nginx',
    date: 'Thu, 02 Mar 2017 14:04:11 GMT',
    'content-type': 'text/html',
    'content-length': '20',
    connection: 'close',
    'www-authenticate': 'Basic realm="Provide an apiKey and secretKey"',
    vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
    'content-encoding': 'gzip' },
```

So it's not eating my API key and secret. Can anyone tell me how to set those as environmental variables in Cloud9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set environment variables in `~/.profile`. Files outside of the workspace directory `/home/ubuntu/workspace` aren't accessible for read-only users so people won't be able to see them.

In the terminal, you can do for example:

```
$> echo "export MAILJET_PUBLIC=foo" >> ~/.profile
$> echo "export MAILJET_SECRET=bar" >> ~/.profile
```

Then, you'll be able to access those variables in Node when using the `connect` method:

```
const mailjet = require ('node-mailjet')
  .connect(process.env.MAILJET_PUBLIC, process.env.MAILJET_SECRET)
```

The runners (from the "run" button) and the terminal will evaluate ~/.profile and make the environment variable available to your app.